# laravel 5 autoload not loading models

Tags: composer-php, autoload, laravel-5

I have this composer config:
under classmap: `"app/models"`
under psr-4:  `"App\\Models\\": "app/models"`

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/models"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "App\\Models\\": "app/models"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
```

Here is my model:

```
namespace App\Models;
class TemplateRow extends Model{
    protected $table = "template_rows";
}
```

in my controller i did: `$row = new TemplateRow();` and I got class not found exception.
I did dump-autoload.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to actually reference the model with it's namespace. You can either write:

```
$row = new \App\Models\TemplateRow();
```

Or add this before the class instead:

```
use App\Models\TemplateRow;
```

---

Also note that you shouldn't even have to add the entry under `psr-4`. If you're directory structure follows the namespacing. To be certain, call your folder `Models` and not `models`

Comment: Isnt this what autoloading is all about? not writing fully qualified names?

Comment: Nope. Autoloading is for making the classes actually available. *Loading* all your PHP files. If you don't want to write full names (or add import statements) you need aliases. (Which you can add in `config/app.php`)