# How to autoload models in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to autoload models in laravel 9,

I want to use models in my blade files, but when i use a model i have to import it writing "`use App\Models\User`", and after i can write "`{{ User::all() }}`", but if i dont import the model first it gives me this error: "`Class "User" not found`", so i want to write "`{{ User::all() }}`" without importing the model first (without writing this: "`use App\Models\User`") in the blade file. How can i autoload them?

Comment: The ```use App\Models\User``` is autoloading the model.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657276/laravel-5-autoload-not-loading-models -- What you really want are aliases, which can be added in `config/app.php`

Comment: *"I want to use models in my blade files"* - MVC Convention suggests that you shouldn't be using Models in Views. So while you _can_ add them to `config/app.php`'s `'alises' => [...]` for this, reconsider what you're trying to accomplish and see if it's more appropriate to be using `$users = User::all();` in a Controller, then passing `$users` to a view via `view('example', ['users' => $users])` (or similar; lots of syntax options for that)

Comment: Hi, i know you are trying to make coding more easily, but notice that  autoload means that it load even you didn't use it, that's makes your app used more resource each request.

Comment: @Charlie is right, do not make alias for models in app.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually alias things in `config/app.php`.

```
'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
    'User' => App\Models\User::class,
    ... your other models here
])->toArray(),
```

This will make `User` available without having to manually write `App\Models\User` every time in the view **and everywhere else**.

---

Just like you can write

```php
use DB;

DB::table('users')->get();
```

instead of

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::table('users')->get();
```

You will be able to write `use User` instead of `use App\Models\User` (though I do not recommend you to do this).

Answer (score -3):

Just like you do in all other Laravel versions, for example:

```php
$query = User::with("posts");
$users = $query->get();
```

Where `User` class needs to define what "posts" means, like:

```php
use \App\Post;

// ...

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'user_id');
}
```

> **Note** that above I query the "User" model, and auto-load any related "Post" model.

Comment: WTF…………………..…..?